# CORS issue while trying to get data from a clip on Vimeo using the api/oEmbed

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, vimeo

I am using fetch to get the data. 
Like so:

```
  getClipMetadata = (url) => {
    const endpoint = 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';

    fetch(`${endpoint}?url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}`, { 
      method: 'get',
      cache: 'no-cache', 
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    })
      .then((response) => { return response.json();})
      .then((res) => console.log("async response received", res))
      .catch((err) => console.log("ajax error -> ", err))    
  }
```

So the error I get is this:
`Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

I thought it looked quite simple from Vimeo's developer [page](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All of the examples I see on that page use `vimeo.com` rather than `www.vimeo.com`. Vimeo likely has a redirect from `www.` to no `www.`.

Comment: Your answer was true in part, sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The endpoint is `'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json'` rather than `'http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json'` and the headers I was sending were causing problems too.

So the final working code looks like this:

```
  getClipMetadata = (url) => {
    const endpoint = 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';

    fetch(`${endpoint}?url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}`, { 
      method: 'get',
      cache: 'no-cache', 
      mode: 'cors',

    })
      .then((response) => { return response.json();})
      .then((res) => console.log("async response received", res))
      .catch((err) => console.log("ajax error -> ", err))    
  }
```